# Play embedded flash object on a https page

Tags: flash, ssl, https, embed, mixed-content

I migrated my blog to ssl/https, but some videos stopped playing so I've tweaked their urls from something like `http://vk.com` to `https://vk.com`

However, I also relay economic video from BFMTV which are in flash, and I'm unable (with the same tweak) to make them work.  BFMTV is a national broadcast so I'm sure there is a way to play their videos on a https site.

I've read things about proxy and things like that, but I haven't found a solution.

Here is the embed code:

```
<object id="flashObj" width="480" height="270" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
    <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /><param name="flashVars" value="videoId=4677448471001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fbfmbusiness.bfmtv.com%2Fmediaplayer%2Fvideo%2Fl-oeil-du-stratege-olivier-delamarche-2812-725574.html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
    <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" /><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=4677448471001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fbfmbusiness.bfmtv.com%2Fmediaplayer%2Fvideo%2Fl-oeil-du-stratege-olivier-delamarche-2812-725574.html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="480" height="270" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: what is BFMTV? Can you show us some code, how you embedded them?

Comment: Thanks you all to have edited my post, its really more readable like that, btw i'm not fluent in english so i apologize for that, Bfmtv is national broadcat news channel : http://www.bfmtv.com/ here is an url with the embed player of course he dont play : https://www.crashdebug.fr/index.php/diversifion/10715-olivier-delamarche-vs-pascale-auclairbfm-business-28-septembre-2015-les-marches-ont-ils-perdu-leurs-fils-conducteurs-fondamentaux